# XStream.fromXML List producing empty list

Tags: java, xstream

I'm trying to learn XStream, and I've followed the API as well as I can understand it, but the following code snippet

```
List<Rectangle> rectangleArray = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
List<Rectangle> rectangleArray2 = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

rectangleArray.add(new Rectangle(18,45,2,6));
String xml = xstream.toXML(rectangleArray);
System.out.println(xml);
xstream.fromXML(xml, rectangleArray2);
System.out.println("new list size: " + rectangleArray2.size());
```

produces output

```
<list>
    <java.awt.Rectangle>
    <x>18</x>
    <y>45</y>
    <width>2</width>
    <height>6</height>
    </java.awt.Rectangle>
</list>
new list size: 0
```

and I cannot figure out why rectangleArray2 is not now a copy of rectangleArray.  Any help?

Comment: Maybe you have to write a custom converter.  I'm not clear on that, but I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handling `List` through `XStream` is bit trickier. To handle the list, you need to define a wrapper class to hold your list e.g.:

```
    public class RectangleList {

        private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

        public List<Rectangle> getRectangles() {
            return rectangles;
        }

        public void setRectangles(List<Rectangle> rectangles) {
            this.rectangles = rectangles;
        }
    }
```

Then add `alias` for list to `RectangleList` class as

```
      xstream.alias("list", RectangleList.class);
```

**and register an implicit converter to manage the list as:**

```
     xstream.addImplicitCollection(RectangleList.class, "rectangles");
```

If you want your `<java.awt.Rectangle>` to print as `<rectangle>`, register ans alias as below:

```
     xstream.alias("rectangle", Rectangle.class);
```

Now use you `RectangleList` class for conversion, it should work fine.

Final test code will look like:

```
    RectangleList recListInput = new RectangleList();
    RectangleList recListOutput = new RectangleList();
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());
    xstream.alias("list", RectangleList.class);
    xstream.alias("rectangle", Rectangle.class);
    xstream.addImplicitCollection(RectangleList.class, "rectangles");

    ArrayList<Rectangle> rectangleArray = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    rectangleArray.add(new Rectangle(18,45,2,6));
    recListInput.setRectangles(rectangleArray);
    String xml = xstream.toXML(rectangleArray);
    System.out.println(xml);
    xstream.fromXML(xml, recListOutput);
    System.out.println("new list size: " + recListOutput.getRectangles().size());
```

This will print output as:

```
    <list>
      <rectangle>
        <x>18</x>
        <y>45</y>
        <width>2</width>
        <height>6</height>
      </rectangle>
    </list>
    new list size: 1
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough response.  If I may ask a follow up: I followed your example and "RectangleList.class" is causing a NullPointerException at runtime.  Any idea why?

Comment: Which line? I shared a working example. Did you define your attribute in RectangleList class as `private List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();` i.e. with initialization?

Comment: On my machine, xstream.addImplicitCollection(RectangleList.class, "rectangles"); is throwing NullPointerException.  I'm working on figuring it out.

Comment: You have added this line after initializing xstream i.e. after this `XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver());` line, right?

Comment: oy.  That was the problem.  Thanks for catching that.  And thanks for a working example.  I'll learn from it.  This will probably help others too.